# IValidatableObject does not get its Validate method invoked

Tags: c#, .net, validation, razor, viewmodel

I have my viewModel class with a Validate method:

```
public class BookViewModel : IValidatableObject
{

    public IEnumerable<(int AuthorId, string AuthorName)>? Authors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int>? AuthorIds { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (NewAuthor.IsNullOrEmpty() && AuthorIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            validationResults.Add(new ValidationResult(
                "Both Author and New Author fields are empty. Chose Authors from the list or enter a new one",
                new[] { nameof(AuthorIds) }));
        }

        return validationResults;
    }
```

Relevant part of the Create view:

```
@model LibApp.WebApp.ViewModels.BookViewModel
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AuthorIds" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="AuthorIds" name="AuthorIds" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AuthorIds" multiple="multiple"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="AuthorIds" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <p>If author doesn't exist, enter new author:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NewAuthor" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="NewAuthor" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="NewAuthor" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

and my controller action for Create POST method which is being called on form submission:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BookViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(model);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ServerError", "Error");
        }
    }
```

The thing is, VM's Validate method should be invoked upon form submission because of the IValidatableObject implementation, but it is not being invoked nor does entry.Value.Errors contain my error. Any ideas why?